# IF/AND formula for Excel

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying get column A (weight) to auto fill column B (Percentage).

- Weights 1-5 need to say 6% in Column B
- Weights 6-10 need to say 8% in Column B
- Weights 11-20 need to say 10% in Column B
- Weights 21+ need to say 10% in Column B

I am trying to work out the formula, but i simply do not have the knowledge or the time to keep trying on this.

Comment: `i simply do not have ... the time to keep trying`, then we probably do not have the time to help.  As this is a volunteer forum.  We have our own jobs to do.

Comment: I say the above to show that ***how*** you ask someone to do you a favor is as important what you ask.  Remember that text does not convey intentions and some may find how you asked as your time is worth more than ours.

Comment: Well I do apologize for the way I asked my question there. I am still trying everything I can on my end to get this to work. I am still not having any success with this formula. As i said, it was the lack of knowledge that made me reach out. I will refrain from using time in the future.Thank you for your advise.

Comment: Thank you, I finially figured it out! Scott your formula was the one I ended up using. I had accidentally enabled a rule that screwed me up from the beginning.

Comment: Now that you have answers you need to mark one as correct.  They all do what you want, but mark the one that you used.  The community will award the others on merit.

Answer (score 1):

I would use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX({0.06,0.08,0.1,0.12},MATCH(A1,{1,6,11,21}))
```

[image]

Or you can use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,{1,0.06;6,0.08;11,0.1;21,0.12},2,TRUE)
```

Or Lookup:

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{1,6,11,21},{0.06,0.08,0.1,0.12})
```

Or HLOOKUP:

```
=HLOOKUP(A1,{1,6,11,21;0.06,0.08,0.1,0.12},2,TRUE)
```

Comment: ... now I'm just tempted to see if theres *another* decent way to do it!

Comment: @CallumDA just wanted to cover all the Lookups, that way the OP can use with whichever they are more comfortable. <sub> at least that is what I want you to believe.</sub>

Comment: Couldn't help myself...`CHOOSE(MIN(ROUNDUP(A11/5,0),3),6%,8%,10%)`

Comment: @CallumDA I thought about that one and decided that I did not want to find a pattern.  good job.

Answer (score 0):

Put in B1 and drag down: `=IF(A1<6,6,IF(A1<11,8,10))`

Answer (score 0):

You need a `nested if` formula. Add this code to `B1` and drag it down.

```
=IF(A1<=5;6%;IF(A1<=10;8%;IF(A1<=20;10%;12%)))
```

**Output example:**

[image]